# Не могу запустить сайт Hello World на хостинге firebase

Tags: html, node.js, веб-программирование, firebase

Делаю следующие действия
1. Зарегистрировалась на сайте firebase (вошла со своего гугл аккаунта) и создала там проект
2. Зашла в проект (пока пустой), перешла на вкладку Hosting 
3. Начала следовать инструкциям: установила node js, в cmd прописала команду npm install - она отработала, дальше перешла в папку на своем компе в котом у меня будет этот проект и запустила последовательно команды firebase login, firebase init, firebase deploy. Они все отработали корректно. Deploy мне выдала мой https. 
4. В самой папке у меня лежит файл index.html, который я хочу задеплоить [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
5. В этом файле index помимо надписи hello world я прописала скрипт привязки к проекту, как было указано на сайте 
6. В браузере index.html отображается 
7. А по указанному в результате команды deploy адресу на хостинге - нет

Comment: Что пишет вам команда deploy?

Comment: Deploying to 'boychikstoldfor'
i deploying database
+ database: rulesready to deploy
i starting release process...

+ Deploy complete!

Hosting Site: https://..........com
Dashboard: https://.........

Visit the URL above or run firebase open

Comment: есть ли ошибки в консоли браузера, когда вы открываете страницу после деплоя?

Comment: Да. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 1):

Покажите firebase.json. index.html дожен лежать в папке, указанной в настройке public этого файла. По умолчанию это папка app. Ваш index находится в ней? см. https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/full-config.html

Comment: Ой, промазал, это должен быть комент

Comment: файл firebase.json создаётся автоматически при команде firebase init в консоли. и у меня выглядит вот так :(

{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  }
}

интересно, что я делаю не так(

Comment: Добавьте в файл строчку "public": "app", создайте папку app, положите туда index.html и сделайте деплой

Comment: Хотя судя по докам, должно работать и без нее

Answer (score 1):

Вы допускаете ту же ошибку, что допускал я. На самом деле всё очень просто.
[image: Смотрите скриншот - ответ на нём]